# Is the following integral positive or not?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integration

Let $n$ be a given even positive integer. We have the following integral
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{j=1}^n(x_i-y_j)dx_1\cdots dx_ndy_1\cdots dy_n\\
&=&\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1\prod\limits_{j=1}^n(x-y_j)dx\right)^ndy_1\cdots dy_n\\
&>&0.
\end{eqnarray}
Let's consider a similar integral where $n$ is also an even positive integer:
$$A_n=\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\cdots\int_0^{2\pi}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{j=1}^n\left(x_i-y_j+i\cos(\alpha_i-\beta_j)\right)dx_1\cdots dx_ndy_1\cdots dy_nd\alpha_1\cdots d\alpha_nd\beta_1\cdots d\beta_n.$$
It is easy to see that $A_n$ is a real number for every $n$. My question is whether $A_n$ is positive or not.

Comment: Did you try any numerical calculations?

Comment: For $n=2$ Maple answers the integral over $\alpha$s and $\beta$s equals $$2\, \left( 8\,{\pi}^{3}A_{{1,1}}A_{{1,2}}A_{{2,1}}A_{{2,2}}+4\,{\pi}^{
3} \right) \pi,
  $$ where $A_{i,j}:=x_i-y_j .$

Comment: Is this a question at the research level? I find it rather an exercise from George Pólya and Gábor Szegő, Aufgaben und Lehrsätze aus der Analysis, 1st edn. 1925.[11] ("Problems and theorems in analysis“). Springer, Berlin 1975 (with Gábor Szegő). Have you asked that in https://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: user64494: Thank you for your attention! This question is not an exercise of any book for me. You said that you found it rather an exercise in the book "Problems and theorems in analysis". Would you please tell me where I can find this exercise？I really want to know more about this question!

Comment: the book mentioned by @user64494 is [here](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-3-642-61983-0), but I don't see this excercise there.